# Need help with illumination of screwed Bezier curves

Tags: lighting

I am trying to illuminate this screwed Bezier curve shape from the inside. It looks like the first picture from some angles, and the second picture from other angles. I want it to always look like the second picture What should I do?

[image: Screenshot of Blender viewport]

[image: Screenshot of Blender viewport]

Comment: Do you mean that you want it to allow light to transmit through it?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out. I had to turn off "Show Backface".

Comment: If you figure it out by yourself, post the answer to the question and accept it. That way it's removed from "Unanswered questions" and people in the future can see better how to solve the problem if they have the same issue.